# What type of PDE is this and what conditions determine the existence of a solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

So I have a system of PDE's essentially consisting of equations of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(\mathbf{x}(t), t)\frac{\partial u(\mathbf{x}(t),t)}{\partial x_i}=c$$
where $c$ is any nonzero constant and $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is a state vector of Itô processes.

I was wondering if anything can be said about what type of PDE this is and what determines the existence of a solution to such a system. Boundary conditions are not provided so if the existence is dependent on very stringent initial/boundary conditions, that is no problem. I'm not necessarily looking for a method to solve this problem, I merely want more information/reading material about these types of expressions.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the unknown? $u$?, $x$. If it is $u$, does it has to satisfy the equation for a particular function $x(t)$ or a family. Some logical quantifiers would be helpful to understand exacly the poblem.

Comment: @themaker The unknown is indeed $u$. It has to satisfy the equation for a particular process $x(t)$ with arbitrary dynamics provided by something of the form $dx_1(t) = a(\mathbf{x}(t), t)dt + b(\mathbf{x}(t), t)d\mathbf{W}(t)$ with $\mathbf{W}$ a vector of Brownian motions.